# "Segmentation fault:11" Assembly error

Tags: assembly, x86

```
section .data
        msg: db 'Hello World di Simona',10  ;the message to write
        len: equ $ - msg                    ;length of the message

section .text
        global _start
        _start:
                mov edx, len                ;save the length
                mov ecx, msg                ;save the message to display
                mov ebx, 1                  ;prepare for the system call
                mov eax, 4
                int 0x80                    ;sytem call
```

Fist question: when I use the linker I get this warning "-macosx_version_min not specificed, assuming 10.7", how can I avoid it?

Second question: It all goes well until I run the executable, I get this error "Segmentation fault: 11"
What does it mean? What is wrong with this code?

Additional information: I am using nasm under Mac OS X, with an Intel Core 2 Duo, today I have benn at my first lesson of Assembly, so I'm new to this language.

Comment: 1. How about specifying -macosx_version_min? 2a. Segmentation fault means that you tried to access memory you don't have access to. 2b. Run the program under the debugger to see where the segmentation fault occurs and what memory you're trying to access.

Comment: What follows `int 0x80`?  If those succeed (and it looks like they should), what should happen afterwards?

Comment: That looks like 32-bit linux style syscalls. I think mac osx uses an entirely different way of performing syscalls.

Answer (score 0):

Linux style syscalls won't work on Mac OS X, as user786653 noted.